# Is there an Py function for sum of clear elements on the main diagonal of a square matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I do the task: Write a function that finds the sum of even elements on the main diagonal of a square matrix (namely even elements, not elements in even positions!). If there are no even elements, then print 0. Use the numpy library.

I don't know what's happening! Can you help me to make my code work? No report bugs only one error!

```py
import numpy as np
def diag_2k(a):
    l = len(a[0])
    for i in range(l):
        if a[i][i]%2 == 0:
            diag_2k = sum([a[i][i]])
        elif a[i][i]%2 == 0 or a[i][i]%2 != 0:
            diag_2k = sum([a[i][i]%2 == 0])
        else:
            diag_2k = 0
    return diag_2k
```

tests examinators report me :

```
Failed. Wrong answer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner solution:

```
sum = sum([i for i in np.diag(matrix) if i % 2 == 0])
```

Alternatively you can loop over the diagonal elements, check if they are even and sum them up:

```
def diag_2k(matrix):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        if matrix[i,i] % 2 == 0:
            sum += matrix[i,i]
    return sum
```